# where to specifiy icon that is display on uninstall app?

Tags: android, icons, uninstallation

I have the correct launcher icon that I want but when I uninstall the app the default Droid green icon appears in the question "do you want to uninstall". Where do I specifiy the icon that is displayed on the uninstall question? (or is it just one of the standard icons - if so which?)

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own questions. What I was referring to was the application icon (logo) on the left side of the action bar. It turned out I had misplaced a closing > in the manifest file just before the definition of the icon for the activity, thus it was using the default Android green one. I moved the > and all is well.